# Javascript mode mixes tabs and spaces for indent

Tags: indentation, javascript, align

My javascript mode indents with a mix of tabs and spaces. I'm ok with the mix if spaces are used for cosmetic alignment, but this is just wrong:

[image]

First level of indentation is spaces, second is tab, third is tab and spaces.

I tried looking for relevant variables. `js-indent-level` is 4.

This is this way with `emacs -q` as well (just using my config above for illustration purpose).

How do I fix this, preferably using spaces only?

Emacs 25.2.2

---

EDIT: Yeah, so I can set `indent-tabs-mode` to `nil`, but isn't the behavior with it at `t` still wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I fix this, preferably using spaces only?

```lisp
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

> Yeah, so I can set indent-tabs-mode to nil, but isn't the behavior with it at t still wrong?

Emacs tries to insert the *"the shortest possible series of tab and space characters"*. This usually means that as soon as you cross 8 characters (the default `tab-width`), you end up with a mixture of tabs and spaces.

> Normally, ***indentation commands insert (or remove) the shortest possible
> series of tab and space characters so as to align to the desired column.***
> Tab characters are displayed as a stretch of empty space extending to
> the next “display tab stop”.  By default, there is one display tab stop
> every ‘`tab-width`’ columns (the default is 8). [emphasis mine]

See `(emacs) Just Spaces` for more information (`C-h r m Just Spaces RET`).

Comment: I'd say that this behavior will never be correct if `tab-width` and `*-indent-level` are not the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"?