# Why is my code indented differently in Emacs than in a Web browser?

Tags: html

Emacs displays the code snippet as shown below.

```
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Code review</li>
          <li>Projects</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Web browsers display the code snippet as shown below.

```
    <header>
      <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Code review</li>
      <li>Projects</li>
    </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

I like to browse the source code of Web pages in my browser (Ctrl + U | View Source).

Is there anything I can do to make the code display with proper indentation in Web browsers?

Comment: Use spaces to indent code. Or set same width for the tab both for emacs and web browser view source.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Is your question about Emacs, or about web browsers?  If the latter, this is the wrong forum for your question.

Comment: @MaximKim: Thanks a lot! I'll answer my question.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, my question is about Emacs. I used to be a regular Emacs Stack Exchange user in the past.

Comment: Is this actually about emacs? It sounds like you want your web browser to act differently, not emacs; if so, this doesn't seem like an emacs question.

Comment: @DanDrake: Emacs mixes spaces with tabs when writing source code. This can be seen using `whitespace-mode`. As a result, it's perfectly normal this code is incorrectly indented in other applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML source code is indented with tabs and spaces. It seems that you need to modify the local variable `indent-tabs-mode`. For simplicity's sake, I've created a [directory local variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html).

```
;; File: .dir-locals.el
;;; Directory Local Variables            -*- no-byte-compile: t -*-
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

((mhtml-mode . ((indent-tabs-mode . nil))))
```

But it didn't work in my configuration (remote connection using Tramp). The manual explains that you also need to enable searching for remote connections by modifying the variable `enable-remote-dir-locals`.

```
;; File: .emacs
(setq enable-remote-dir-locals t)
```

See also: [Javascript mode mixes tabs and spaces for indent](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/61349/41670)